# How to exclude a disk so that the OS will not use it?

Tags: hard-disk

We have an HDD that is probably having too much bad sectors. The notebook boots extremly slow from it.

We put the disk in another notebook (good) via a CR-ROM HDD case.

But now that good notebook boots extreme slow with it.. (booting from the good disk)

**Q**: How can we exclude the bad HDD from the OS noticing it?* (**maybe some udev rule** to only allow the good disk, then after boot, enabled it, so we can try to rescue the data from the bad HDD?)

*besides puting it in a USB-HDD case so we can plug it in after boot.

The OS is RHEL 6.6 Desktop.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick then they couldn't rescue its data

Comment: Sorry, misread your question.

Answer (score 2):

You don't want RHEL to *notice* it, or you simply don't want it to mount it automatically? For the latter, it's simple: you modify `/etc/fstab`. Your new drive will have new UUIDs, which you can determine by running `blkid` which will output all your partitions and UUIDs.

In `/etc/fstab`, comment-out lines that refer to the physical disk and replace them with UUID specific ones, like this:

```
UUID=41c4428-fca3-41a6-8196-c8115a9b7aa8  /disk2p2      ext3    defaults,errors=remount-ro 0       1
```

Reboot. The old disk will still be unmounted, but mountable.